# Retrieve dynamic keys of an object in json file using php

Tags: php, json, regex

I have a huge 27GB JSON file that is nested, and some object keys (e.g. foo_12354, foo_12356, foo_13589 are dynamically generated. I want to extract the object keys and output them in a column as thus:

```
      `FOO ID`
     `foo_12354`
     `foo_12356`
     `foo_13589`
```

Here is [my json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdTN5eHJoZHZMeG8/view?usp=sharing).
I am employing a [JSON pull parser for PHP 7](https://github.com/pcrov/JsonReader) due to the size of the file, and thus did not use json_decode() to turn my json document into php array. 
I have attempted to use preg_match() but got this error message:
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:

I used foreach() as used in some posts in stackoverflow (e.g. [PHP - print object key from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331767/php-print-object-key-from-json)) but also got no result. I have been able to retrieve information from objects that are static, but I am having problem with objects that are dynamically generated. I will be glad for help. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php';
    use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
    $reader = new JsonReader();
    $reader->open("myjsonfile.json");
    $fo = fopen("mycsv.csv", "w" );
    fputs($fo, "companyID1".PHP_EOL);
    while($reader->read()) {
    preg_match('/^foo_/', $reader, $companyID_matches);
    $companyID_match = $companyID_matches[0];   
    if ($reader->read("$companyID_match")){
    $companyID1 = null;
    $companyID = $reader->key();
    }   

 fputs($fo,  $companyID.$uhcName.PHP_EOL);
 }
 $reader->close();
```

Comment: $reader->name() will give you the key. $reader is the json reader itself, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php';
    use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
    $reader = new JsonReader();
    $reader->open("myjsonfile.json");
    $fo = fopen("mycsv.csv", "w" );
    fputs($fo, "companyID1".PHP_EOL);
    while($reader->read()) {
    if (preg_match('/^foo_/', $reader->name())){
        $companyID = $reader->name();
        fputs($fo,  $companyID.PHP_EOL);
    }   
 }
 $reader->close();
```

Here I simplified your code a bit, removed useless variables (sorry if they were usefull, but they weren't used/defined anywhere. What I do is loop through the read, which will give us each key-value pair. Check if the key is matches the pattern, and put it in the file.